# Expressing matrix as its orthogonal

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, functions

This relates with my question in [Proving sum of two matrices to be identity](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/586185/proving-sum-of-two-matrices-to-be-identity).

Given $m<n$ and non singular $n\times n$ symmetric matrix $A$. Suppose that $H$ and $K$ be $m \times n$ and $n\times (n-m)$ matrices such that rank$(H)=m$, rank$(K)=n-m$, and $HK=0$. Now, define
\begin{equation}
Q=K(K^TAK)^{-1}K^TA.
\end{equation}

Can we express $Q$ as a function of $H$ and $A$ or the other matrices which is independent with $K$? I've made some guesses like in the given link above, but there are some counterexamples of my guess. Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: You have at least one typo, as the product $K^\top AK$ isn't defined. But even when you fix that, it won't be invertible.

Comment: Why is it not defined?