# Explicit formula of a matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-equations

I have a problem below:

Given a full rank $m\times n$ matrix $H$ with $m<n$. Let $K$ is an $n \times (n-m)$ matrix in which each column is the element of the basis of the subspace $\{x\in \mathbb{R}^n:Hx=0\}.$ Now define 
\begin{equation}
P=K(K^TAK)^{-1}K^TA.
\end{equation}
where $A$ is a given non singular symmetric matrix. Can we express $P$ explicitly in term of $H$ and doesn't contain matrix $K$? Thank you in advance. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: What have you tried?  What reason to you believe that expression does not depend on your choice of $K$?

Comment: I believe it because $P$ is independent with the choice of the basis of the subspace {x∈Rn:Hx=0}. And I have tried in making guess [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/586185/proving-sum-of-two-matrices-to-be-identity). But someone gave a counterexample in my guess.

Answer (score 1):

Try to consider
$$
P=I-Q=I-A^{-1}H^T(HA^{-1}H^T)^{-1}H.
$$

Then
$$
H(P+Q)=H[A^{-1}H^T(HA^{-1}H^T)^{-1}H+K(K^TAK)^{-1}K^TA]=H
$$
and
$$
K^TA(P+Q)=K^TA[A^{-1}H^T(HA^{-1}H^T)^{-1}H+K(K^TAK)^{-1}K^TA]=K^TA.
$$
Hence, if $[H^T,A^TK]$ is not rank-deficient, $P+Q=I$.

Comment: Algebraic Pavel Thanks for your help. But, how can we conclude $P+Q=I$ from the second and third equation?

Comment: @Jlamprong It holds only if the *square* matrix $[H^T,A^TK]$ is not rank-deficient (nonsingular). Then from the second and third equation, you have $[H^T,A^TK]^T(P+Q)=[H^T,A^TK]^T$. Premultiplying with $[H^T,A^TK]^{-T}$ gives $P+Q=I$.

Comment: OK, thanks for your help.